# How to save each group of rows (in a DataFrame) in separate Excel files?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

first of all i want to say that i am new to python .i have an excel file which has multiple columns. and some of the columns has filter(dropdown with multiple selections). i want make excel files based on columns like this :
columns : x , y , z , t , date , hour
note: in columns DATE and HOUR we multiple selection. for example column HOUR, has filters like 00:00 , 1:00 , 2:00 , 3:00, 4:00 and ..........

**what i am looking for is creating new excel files based on the  rows with these conditions:**
newExcel1: date 1, hour 00:00

---

newexcel2: date 1, hour 1:00

---

newExcel3: date 1: hour 2:00

---

---

newExcel24:day 1  hour 23:00

---

newExcel25: day 2  hour 00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a loop on `Day-Hour` column with `groupby`:

```
# Read your excel file
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

# Postprocessing here (rename columns, etc)
...

# Export data in multiple files
for idx, (ts, subdf) in enumerate(df.groupby('Day-Hour'), 1):
    subdf.to_excel(f'newExcel{idx}.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: works out ..... but i have a question : what are  idx, ts???

Comment: Just some variables you define, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns a tuple containing a count (here from 1) and the values returned by [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) which is an iterator too. `ts` will contain all unique `Day-Hour` values and `subdf` the filtered dataframe (like Excel).

Comment: "idx" and "ts" are the values that tou define it by yourself?

Comment: Yes it is. Choose the name you want. Replace `idx` with `i` if you prefer or `ts` by `group_name`. It's a simple loop.